# flagged question - flag declined - question deleted

Tags: discussion, flagging, deleted-questions

Just wondering. I flagged a [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64802/using-js-other-code-to-access-files-bypassing-ad-sharepoint-permissions) about code to bypass AD/SharePoint permissions to access files. The flag was declined and I was told to comment rather than flag. But some time later the question was "removed from SharePoint Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation" and can now no longer be accessed. Was my flag valid in the first place, then?  If so, why does it still show as declined in my profile, but the question has been moderated away?

Comment: maybe user deleted question him/her self ?

Comment: @MuhammadRaja: You can't moderate yourself. At least not in this context.

Comment: Difficult to answer without seeing the question.

Comment: It's in my flag history http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/3476 -- The title of the question was "Using js/other code to access files bypassing AD/sharepoint permissions". The hover popup shows the following in the preview: "My key goal is to use some form of js as a basis for security authentication in sharepoint (e.g. sessions).I have a subsite within my organization and it was locked down by the admins who stopped ..." -- In the question body the asker described how s/he wanted to circumvent the restrictions that the IT staff had set on the site.

Comment: My flag comment was "Not sure if bypassing security is a welcome topic". It was overruled by someone with the comment " declined - It's a valid question, and in my opinion the answer is "don't". Please expand your comment into an answer rather than flag. Thanks." But now the question has been deleted for reasons of moderation. Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

Just saw this, and I am pretty sure I declined this flag.

My reasoning, from what I remember, was that while technically bad practice, there was nothing wrong with the question *per se*. It really needs a good answer explaining why this is a bad idea. I don't think there is any reason to censor these sorts of questions - rather they are an opportunity to add useful information to the site as Anders says.

If the question had obviously malicious or facetious intent then that would be a different matter.

No idea why the question was deleted. Community is a robot. It may be responding to a number of delete requests reaching a threshold.

Comment: No worries. Thanks @SPDoctor, for taking the time to clarify. I was not aware that there are robots scouring and deleting questions, but thinking about it, it **does** make sense.

Comment: Sorry I can't add more detail - I don't know that much about the inner workings of StackExchange. The SE team are tweaking these rules and algorithms all the time.

Comment: That's fine. I was not expecting you to justify or explain to me the inner workings of SE. I'm still on a learning curve in this here place and often marvel at how things work here. It's not a bad place to be. No grovels from my side after the explanations given above.

Comment: We don't have an option "Helpful but declined" when dealing with flags. Your other several dozen flags were all helpful and were acted on. Please keep flagging posts that may need mod attention. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why "Community" (a special account on StackOverflow) have deleted this Q, but I agree with my fellow moderator that even though a question is not a best practice, it should be allowed.

The answers should then ofcourse mirror the fact that this is not a good practice, so that this is evident for other users later browsing by.

My reasoning is that the more info there is to be found describing bad practices, the better the chance that the bad practices is not followed in the future?

Comment: The Community account is probably enforcing the general SE theme of "... if what you are aiming for is malicious, please take it somewhere else (and by that I mean outside Stack Exchange)." quoted from here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133497/is-there-any-se-site-where-questions-related-to-hacking-are-on-topic

Comment: Community is a robot. If one of the SE admins had done it you would see their individual moderator account.